# How to untangle delegate_to and become in Ansible? (how to use become to connect with ssh?)

Tags: ssh, ansible

Consider the following layout for the current directory:

```
.
├── foobar.yml
└── roles
    └── foobar
        └── tasks
            └── main.yml
```

Suppose we have the following tasks for the `foobar` role (`roles/foobar/tasks/main.yml`):

```
---

- add_host:
    name: "baz"
    ansible_user: "root"
    ansible_become: yes
    ansible_ssh_host: "{{container.ip}}"
    ansible_ssh_host_key_checking: no
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{container.privkey}}"
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"

- wait_for:
    port: 22
    host: "{{container.ip}}"
    timeout: 30
    search_regex: OpenSSH

- apt:
    pkg:
      - vim-nox
      - lsof
  delegate_to: "baz"
  become: true
  become_user: root
```

... and the following playbook:

```
---

- name: Configuring container and host
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    container:
      ip: "172.17.0.2"
      privkey: "/root/root_ssh/id_rsa"
  roles:
    - foobar
```

OpenSSH is available on the IPv4 given in the playbook and the private key exists in the given path (`u=rw,go=`, i.e. 0600, with its parent directory having 0700). During my tests I have verified all these things (e.g. with `stat` and `debug`).

The last task fails as follows:

```
TASK [foobar : apt] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/username/ansible/test/roles/foobar/tasks/main.yml:18
<172.17.0.2> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<172.17.0.2> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/root/root_ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ControlPath=/home/username/.ansible/cp/0689044634 172.17.0.2 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~root && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.17.0.2> (255, '', "Warning: Permanently added '172.17.0.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nno such identity: /root/root_ssh/id_rsa: Permission denied\r\nroot@172.17.0.2: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n")
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '172.17.0.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nno such identity: /root/root_ssh/id_rsa: Permission denied\r\nroot@172.17.0.2: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

The output of `ssh` is:

```
Warning: Permanently added '172.17.0.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
no such identity: /root/root_ssh/id_rsa: Permission denied
root@172.17.0.2: Permission denied (publickey).
```

... which I also get when running an equivalent `ssh` command from the command line as myself (i.e. without `sudo`). The error cause here is that `/root/root_ssh/id_rsa` is inaccessible to the user running `ssh`. If I use `sudo` to invoke `ssh` with an equivalent command, it works like a charm.

In order for `ssh` to be able to access the private key, though, it has to be invoked as `root` already.

**Q:** So how can I get Ansible to use `become` *while establishing* the connection with `ssh` (i.e. `ssh` running as `root`)?

---

Ansible Version

```
$ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.9.4
  config file = /home/username/ansible/precitec/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/username/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) [GCC 7.4.0]
```

---

### What I have tried

- tacking a `become` on the `add_host` task
- set `ansible_ssh_executable: "/usr/bin/sudo -- /usr/bin/ssh"` (and also `sudo -- ssh` and combinations thereof) in order to force Ansible to use sudo to call `ssh`. Alas, the result was that Ansible ended up using Paramiko.
- ... get creative and set `ansible_ssh_executable` and `ansible_ssh_args` (see below)
- moving the `apt` task inside a `block` where the `apt` task was using `delegate_to`, but the outer block was *also* using `become`, also to no avail (see below)

None of that helped.

#### Setting `ansible_ssh_executable` and `ansible_ssh_args`

```
    ansible_ssh_executable: "/usr/bin/sudo"
    ansible_ssh_args: "-- /usr/bin/ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s"
```

Ansible appears to check the `ansible_ssh_executable` value, so giving a full command line (such as `sudo -- ssh`) in there isn't possible.

#### Wrapping in a block ...

```
- name: Install packages
  block:
    - apt:
        pkg:
          - vim-nox
          - lsof
      delegate_to: "baz"
      become: true
  become: true
```

Comment: The only two solutions I see to your current problem are 1) `sudo ansible-playbook foobar.yml` or 2) make the key accessible to the current user. Become will not help for anything on the controller: it is only used on the target. Your current try is totally useless on the target host: you are already connecting as root (`ansible_user: "root"`) and then using `become` to escalate as root again.

Comment: @Zeitounator: thanks, I appreciate the feedback. Agreed, I also thought that last part pretty redundant. But this _also_ doesn't work if it's running on a remote host. I.e. another docker host running the container. The issue is exactly the same. I simplified that part to get an MWE. Did I oversimplify, is that what you're suggesting? `sudo` is currently the workaround, but that obviously only works when running the playbook on `localhost`. Alas, the goal would be to run it remotely as well, but the problem that there is no way to express "elevate `ssh`" remains ...

Comment: Wherever you run it, the key needs to be accessible to the user running it. Ansible cannot 'elevate ssh' it runs ssh with the current user and then escalate privileges on the remote host. The only way to 'elevate ssh' is to 'elevate ansible' all together.

Comment: @Zeitounator so even though the host would be remote and my task would use `become: true` the connection (`add_host`) happens from the _controller_, not from the machine on which the task is supposed to run? That seems odd. I would expect that elevation on a remote host happens before _that remote host_ connects to some other machine (like in my scenario).

Comment: Now I finally get your question.... and your major misunderstanding of `delegate_to`. In your apt task it simply changes the remote host to baz. The baz host witll be contacted by the controller.

Comment: Thanks, @Zeitounator. That's a valuable piece in the puzzle.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation might shade some light on the concept.